# Late Answer Review Queue; answer is sort of an answer but sort of isn't

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, late-answers

In the late answers review queue, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665008/how-to-extract-information-from-input-method/26405098#26405098).

Now this question technically asks, "Is there any way to...", which the answer does cover. However, it seems implied that the asker would have liked a "How?" as well (especially from the title of the question), which this answer doesn't cover at all. Do I flag as NAA, as VLQ, or don't flag at all? For this time around, I've skipped it, but would like to know what to do in the future if such a case arises again.

It appears that the answer in question has been deleted since I have asked this question, which lets me know that it should indeed have been flagged with something, now the question is just what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag it as "not an answer" or "very low quality". Whatever it's trying to say, it's not answering the question or helping anybody.